# How to GROUP BY with an exception?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Here is my simplied code:

```
SELECT 
   a.user_id as User_ID,
   min(b.a_day) as Date_from,
   max(b.a_day) as Date_to,
   c.code as ID 
FROM a, b, c 
WHERE 
   a_day > (day, -15, getdate())
GROUP BY 
   a.user_id,
   c.code
```

Query gives the following output:

```
User ID date_from   date_to     id    
1234567 2016-06-13  2016-06-13  B
1234567 2016-06-17  2016-06-17  A
12345672016-06-18  2016-06-18   A
1234567 2016-06-19  2016-06-19  A
1234567 2016-06-20  2016-06-20  A
1234567 2016-06-21  2016-06-21  C
1234567 2016-06-22  2016-06-22  C
1234567 2016-06-23  2016-06-23  D
```

I need something like this:

```
User ID date_from   date_to     id
1234567 2016-06-13  2016-06-13  B
1234567 2016-06-17  2016-06-20  A
1234567 2016-06-21  2016-06-22  C
1234567 2016-06-23  2016-06-23  D
```

When I use min() and max() function with group by, it aggregates fine for all records but I have to aggregate only dates with the same ID day after day.

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Add sample table data. (That gives the specified result.)

Answer (score 4):

You can do it with conditional grouping by using `CASE EXPRESSION` in the `GROUP BY` clause :

```
SELECT 
   a.user_id as User_ID,
   min(b.a_day) as Date_from,
   max(b.a_day) as Date_to,
   c.code as ID 
FROM a, b, c 
WHERE 
   a_day > (day, -15, getdate())
GROUP BY 
   a.user_id,
   c.code,
   CASE WHEN c.code in ('B','D') THEN b.a_day ELSE 1 END
```

Which will generate this as the `GROUP BY` clause :

```
c.code = 'B' -> a.user_id,c.code,b.a_day
c.code <> 'B' -> a.user_id,c.code,1
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, however I have more IDs than only A and B. So I can't get a data relying on these records. I think it should check if there are some continued dates and then make group by separately for two groups (continued and single days).

Comment: I don't understand, you should mention everything in the question! What is the issue here? There are more codes that should be grouped daily? Which are they?

Comment: Sorry for that. ID can be A,B, C, D, and so on. The most important for me is to find a solution that makes possible to get a data with same ID for single day and dates range for day after day. Just added to my code another ID.

Comment: So only `B` type should be grouped by date as well? This is what my query does.. @aoc24

Comment: There can be D type as well which should be grouped same as B, but separately (code edited).

Comment: @aoc24 See edit, each type that appears inside the `IN()` will be grouped by date as well .

Comment: Yes, it works fine but I can't put there any ID permanently. It's a flexible data depends on date. Now it looks like in my example. for the next two weeks it can be quite different (A and C should be IN() for example).

Comment: That's the reason why I can't use your solution. It's a flexible data. For example for this week A and B can be separately days, for the next week C and D.

Comment: @aoc24 ..... That's what I'm asking! no body can give you a solution if you don't explain how on earth are we supposed to find them? Why this week `A and B` and why the next one its `C and D` ? What are the rules of it ?

Comment: It's a kind of personel absence report. ID is a type of absence (there are about 12 different IDs) which are put into system manually. There can be a single day of absence or few days (day after day). I have to get this data from database in a form that I showed in my post.

Comment: @aoc24 Do you mean in other words -> If there are more than 1 record for the same type(different dates) , then group with out a date. Else -> group with the date? If so , you don't even need the case, it should work with your query..

Comment: There can be both types of records - multiple days: 2016-06-17 - 2016-06-20 with ID A and as well a single day 2016-06-24 with ID A. As the output should be 2 rows: 2016-06-17 - 2016-06-20 and  2016-06-24 - 2016-06-24

Comment: So, in other words, 1 record for each group of continuously days and a record for each record with out a continuously days? @aoc24

Comment: Can be one or more records for each group of continuously days and as well one or more out a continuously days.

Comment: @aoc24 Please edit the question with an example of all your expected rules! because for now - my query will return the output you requested , so show me when it doesn't .